# How do I return a null value if there is an answer >0 in a column I'm using to determine the need to compute for the cell?

Tags: excel

I have a sheet which has 5 columns, as follows: Start Date, Due Date, Date Completed, Days Completed Late, and Days Ahead/ Behind Schedule. The Due Date and Date Completed are pre filled, the Day completed is filled in by the user; Days Completed Late is a formula. I want Days Ahead/ Behind Schedule to compute, but I don't want anything in there if the task has been completed. I have the following formula, =IF(F3=""&E3>TODAY(),TODAY()-E3,G3), but it returns an answer no matter what.

START DATE  DUE DATE    Date Comp   Days Comp Late     Days Behind
09/01/13    09/02/13    09/10/13    8              59
09/01/13    09/02/13                               59

How do I make the Days Behind return a null value if there is a number in the Days Compl Late Column?

Answer (score 0):

With some guesswork, including that you want null when there is **not** a number in the Days Compl Late Column, I think:

```
=IF(G3="","",IF(F3=""&E3>TODAY(),TODAY()-E3,G3))
```

may suit IF your formula works otherwise.